# Statistics on a column of values

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I have a class project that I am working on as an engineering student but the course is probability and statistics so I don't really know how to make sense or use of what I am learning so I thought of asking for help.

I am currently working on a project and I want to ask for generic help with what to use based on what I have learned in class and how to make sense of what I am using.

Without further adou:

I have a column that has roughly 1000 rows.

The values in the row range from 500 to 1000.

So for example:

1000
987
878
679
612
501
500
467
678
546
659
908

The values above represent the amount of water in a container. The water is never allowed to go below 500 Liters or above 1000 Liters so it is bounded between 500 and 1000.

I have learned Normal distribution in class, sampling methods, hypothesis testing, standard deviation, variances, Central Limit Theorem, Point Estimators and Confidence Intervals.

Now using what I learned in class, what methods listed above should I use to make sense of the data I have obtained? I honestly don't really know for my application of water in a container what I can use to explain my data.

Basically, the water in a container is being monitored by sensors which tell how much water in Liters the container has and that is the data I showed in the column. It is the job of a person to go and refill the water when it is getting near 500 Liters.

How can I use my statistics and what do they really mean or show in this context?

Some of you may be confused with what I wrote so please feel free for elborations. Thank you for helping me understand what I am learning in class as an application.

Comment: Yeah, your question is pretty unclear to me. Does each measurement represent the amount of water at a different time? What about the data are you trying to understand? The mean and standard deviation of the data set would definitely aid in understanding its distribution, and if you're trying to look at that distribution graphically, a histogram seems appropriate. Also, the way you're using "column" and "row" seem to be incorrect and this confuses me further. Do you just mean you have roughly 1000 values, or does each of the ~1000 rows contain multiple values?

Comment: @DivergentQueries Thank for asking elaboration. Each measurement represents the quantity in litres at that moment in time so as you go down the list you go farther back in time with the bottom entry in list being the very first entry and the top entry being the last entry in the list. There are 1000 entries in total so that is my sample size n. I only have one sample of size 1000 but do you recommend I instead do something like a sample size of 5 but do 1000 samples instead? Right now I have roughly 1000 values but I COULD do 1000 rows that contain 5 values each row. Which is better?

Comment: Right now those list of values are instantaneous values in time with continuation. This means I hit "record" and the meter reads 1000 L but as water is taken it records more values of the water lowering then once the meter hits 500 L, someone refills and it goes back to 1000 L reading then again the cycle repeats. The values in that list are simply a recording of the cycle process. It would be very troublesome to record the values of one cycle and count that as one sample then keep sampling more samples. So right now I just have one sample with a large sample size.

Comment: The sample size though really holds numerous cycles worth of data. One more thing, each entry in that list is entered 5 seconds later. So entry 2 was entered 5 seconds after entry one was entered. Entry 3 5 seconds after entry 2 was entered.

Comment: Good, I understand your sample more clearly now. (You should probably edit your initial post to include this information.) Anyway, the strategies you use will depend on what you want to know. As I said, a histogram will give you a nice view of the distribution of values. If you want to incorporate time into your visualization, maybe a scatterplot of volume vs time. If you want the mean volume, well...check the mean. The standard deviation can give you a rough estimate of the "variability" of your data, but it's hard to do much with if you don't have more knowledge of the data's distribution.

Comment: @DivergentQueries are you please able to provide some examples for a better understanding? How can I use confidence intervals? I asked my teacher and she was telling me to make normal distributions and calculating mean but that would probably get me a 25% instead of the 100% I am aiming for. The data is continuous meaning that it cannot just jump from 500 to 1000 L or 1000 L to 500 L without any values in between showing the transition..Does that help?

Comment: Are your data normally distributed? If so, it is easy to use the mean and standard deviation to formulate confidence intervals. One (very rough, but probably sufficient here) way to check the normality of your data is to make a histogram and see whether it looks like a normal distribution. Another strategy, which should be used in conjunction with the first, is to determine how much of your data fall within one, two, and three standard deviations of the mean; if they are normally distributed, they will roughly follow the 68-95-99.7 rule (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule).

Comment: @DivergentQueries I will give that a try in Excel now with the data I have. My prof said something about a function in Excel that will determine what kind of distribution your data has.